# Difference between $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] and $_COOKIE

Tags: php, cookies, destroy

What's the difference between **$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']** and **$_COOKIE**?

Why *$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']* isn't documented in the PHP Manual?

I'm creating a class for managing cookies, and I want to make a function that destroy all cookies that are set. I must destroy from $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] variable, like:

```
public function destroy_all() {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, null, 1, $this->cookie_path);
    }
}
```

or with $_COOKIE array, like:

```
public function destroy_all() {
    foreach($_COOKIE as $name => $cookie) {
        setcookie($name, null, 1, $this->cookie_path);
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is unclear or not useful for getting downvotes?

Comment: You say "`$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] isn't documented`", why do you think to use it then? Your questions title does not match the content, please be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use the value in `$_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"]`. It's not documented, so it's probably not reliable. more details [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
.Note that the `$_COOKIE` variable not will hold multiple cookies with the same name

Answer (score 1):

Not all server has the this global variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']`. On my share host, they don't have this variable available. However, `$_COOKIE` variable is usually guaranteed available.

Answer (score 0):

actually $_SERVER is a global variable that include these global variables

$_SERVER = $_COOKIE + $_SESSION + $_GET + $_POST

its possible to user $_SERVER  to get cookies but Not standard and maybe you get conflicts in your project

Comment: Not True. $_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. See [Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) . $_SERVER is not containing $_COOKIE , $_SESSION , $_GET , $_POST as you describe.